# Its every project android native (kotlin) should use jetpack compose ? or its fine to use xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

Its every project android native (kotlin) should use jetpack compose ? or its fine to use xml ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask this question is opinion based and not suitable for stackoverflow

Comment: It's ok if you want to use XML. Compose is just another way for developers to create their app's UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about ok or not. It's about your convenience you can choose to Jetpack Compose or XML or both in the same app. But it would be better if the app is entirely in Compose or XML way because `code maintenance` is different for both.

Happy coding...